# allow php invoked by exec() to write to console

Tags: php

I invoked a php file by exec() doing this :

```
<?php
$cmd = "php -q nah.php";
exec($cmd);
echo "lalal";
?>
```

and the nah.php has this :

```
<?php
echo "yaya";
sleep(3);
?>
```

It does sleep for 3 seconds but the file can echo out to the command.
How can I do echo the output from nah.php

Comment: How you can do **what**?

Comment: echo to console which is in nah.php

Comment: and check the edit now i fixed. I though i had written it earlier :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to capture the output of another process, then you can use [backticks](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

```
$output=`command line`;
```

or capture it with [exec()](http://php.net/exec)

```
exec('command line', $output);
```

However, both of these techniques only give the output when the external process has run to completion. If you want to grab the output as it happens, you can use [popen](http://php.net/popen) (or [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open) for more control), e.g. something like this

```
$handle = popen('command line 2>&1', 'r');
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $read = fread($handle, 2096);
    echo $read;
}
pclose($handle);
```

The `2>&1` at the end of the command line is a handy idiom if running within a shell like [bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html). It redirects stderr to stdout, so any errors the command generates will be returned to PHP. There are more advanced ways to capture stderr, this just makes it easy.

Comment: Yea that's what i ve been looking for the the popen.
But can u also give me an example of proc_open() because i want input output as well

Answer (score 3):

Change your first script to:

```
<?php
$cmd = "php -q nah.php";
echo `$cmd`;
echo "lalal";
```

Comment: @kritya: Backtick delimiter is used to execute system command. So you execute the command `php -q ...` and `echo` the results of execution

Comment: The backtick operator executes a command and returns the ouput: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Answer (score 1):

exec() creates a new console and executes the php file there, it returns the output in an array (One element per line return) that is passed in as a second argument. So if you change your code to:

```
<?php
$output = array();
$cmd = "php -q nah.php";
exec($cmd, $output);
$lines = count($output);
for($i = 0; $i < $lines; $i++)
  echo $output[$i];
echo "lalal";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote ouput instead of output. Fixed it

Comment: Code is too bloated. It can be shortened to 2 lines: 1) exec 2) echo implode